# my UINavigatioBar is not on the top of view - programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am creating a UINavigationBar using the following,

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [view addSubview: navigationController.view];
```

How come it shows up like this?

[image: simulator]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/2f93b5b0c1f4c49e234b9d4ac964c606.png))</sub>

I want it to be on the top of the view but there is space there, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating things correctly. You should create your view controller, then create a navigation controller, passing the view controller as the nav controller's root controller. Then you make the nav controller the app's root controller.

```
UIViewController *vc = ... // create your view controller
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
window.rootViewController = nc;
```

The code you posted does not create a nav bar, it creates an entire navigation controller.

Answer (score -2):

Put this code to ViewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [view addSubview: navigationController.view];
}
```

Also you should resize nav controller to self controller bouns

Comment: This is not the way to put a view controller in a nab controller nor is it a way to add just a nav bar to a view controller.

Comment: Second what rmaddy says. Read up on view controller containment, starting at -[UIViewController addChildViewController:]